# css-overiding issue

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have a problem with the display of the image scroller in my page on my site in IE and the entire menu doesnt display properly in Google chrome, only in Mozilla,
the site address is:

[gilt.martinduys.com](http://gilt.martinduys.com/)

Please view the above link in IE, Mozilla and Chrome

I'd like it to render exactly like Mozilla.

IE Problem - The image scroller blocks 1 to 5 is not displaying in its correct position.

Chrome - the menu is right at the top of the site

Mozilla - Perfect

I'd really appreciate some help, thankyou.

Comment: it looks exactly same in my chrome 8 and ff 3.6.12. In both the menu is shifted to far left

Comment: Mozilla what? Mozilla browser or Firefox?

Comment: is this a dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396558/css-overriding-issue

Answer (score 2):

Following my comment,

`#new_navigation:`
Removing background-color: black; and adding margin:0 auto fixes the problem
[image]

Doing similar in mozzila: 
[image]

If these are the final looks you want I suggest you make the above changes.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, I think you should add `position: relative` to the `imageWrapper` element. By the way: not all is well in Mozilla either; try resizing.

Answer (score 0):

I openend your site in IE and the image slider has very much space between the image and the top menu.

Use `margin: -175px auto 0px auto` on `<ul id="imageScroller">` to show the image directly under the menu.

And I think that you should use `position: relative` on `<div id="imageWrapper">`

Comment: the imagewrapper is referenced in a other style sheet externally, and this is the current settings to is